# Why does my benchmark show same fast performance for ranging over a slice by value vs. index?

Tags: go

```golang
type Item struct {
    A int
    B [1024]byte
}
 
func BenchmarkRange1(b *testing.B) {
    s := make([]Item, 1024)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, v := range s {
            _ = v.A
        }
    }
}
 
func BenchmarkRange2(b *testing.B) {
    s := make([]Item, 1024)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for i := range s {
            _ = s[i].A
        }
    }
}
```

Now, take a look at the result of the benchmark.

```sh
go test -bench=BenchmarkRange -benchmem main/copy
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: main/copy
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
BenchmarkRange1-12       4577601               260.9 ns/op             0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkRange2-12       4697178               254.9 ns/op             0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      main/copy       3.391s
```

Isn't it to copy elements when range slice by value? Why the performance is same? What optimization does the compiler do when we range the slice by value？

When I fobidden the optimization of compiler by compiling option "-gcflags=-N", I will get the expected result:

```sh
go test -bench=BenchmarkRange -benchmem -gcflags=-N main/copy
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: main/copy
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
BenchmarkRange1-12         39004             29481 ns/op              27 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkRange2-12        777356              1572 ns/op               1 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      main/copy       3.169s
```

Who can explain how the compiler to optimize.

Comment: Also, even if the loop isn't optimized away, `s[i].A` copies a slice element too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out this question.

Why would the compiler optimize the above test code? Because the code actually only takes the value of the last slice element, the previous loop operation can be skipped.

If it is the following code, then the compiler will not be able to optimize and must iterate over all the elements.

```
func BenchmarkRange1(b *testing.B) {
    items := make([]Item, 1024)
    tmps := make([]int, 1024)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for j := range items {
            tmps[j] = items[j].id
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkRange2(b *testing.B) {
    items := make([]Item, 1024)
    tmps := make([]int, 1024)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for j, item := range items {
            tmps[j] = item.id
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the default optimizations, your inner loop in both both `BenchmarkRange1` and `BenchmarkRange2` is being compiled down to an empty loop with 1024 iterations, as if you had written your inner loop like:

```golang
    for i := 0; i < 1024; i++ {

    }
```

In both of your examples, the compiler is smart enough to recognize that you aren't doing anything inside the inner loop (that is, not making use of `v`, `v.A`, `s[i]`, or `s[i].A`).

[go.godbolt.org](https://go.godbolt.org) is a great resource for looking at the assembly the Go compiler produces. For example, the inner loop in `BenchmarkRange1` gets compiled down to the following (which zeros out AX, then loops 1024 times):

```
        XORL    AX, AX
Range1_pc39:
        INCQ    AX
        CMPQ    AX, $1024
        JLT     Range1_pc39
```

You can look at the complete output here, along with handy tooltips that (usually) explain the different assembly instructions:
https://go.godbolt.org/z/raTPjTrYG

(To make your example shorter, I dropped the testing package; the `//go:nosplit` comments aren't really needed, but slightly simplify the resulting assembly).